# Can I drive in the United States with a Spanish issued drivers licence?

Tags: usa, driving, spanish-citizens

I am travelling to the US - can I drive using my Spanish driver's licence ?

Comment: https://www.usa.gov/visitors-driving

Answer (score 6):

If you have a valid Spanish license you may be able to [rent a car in the US](https://www.usa.gov/visitors-driving#item-37267), however that alone may not be enough. Depending on the state you're visiting, you probably need to also have an International Driving Permit with you. Georgia for example requires that. You'd have to get the IDP from Spain before you leave.

There could be other requirements such as age for example, it varies between states. You can find the list of [DMVs](https://www.usa.gov/motor-vehicle-services) here, from there you can find each state's specific requirements.

Comment: Even when not required, it is always good to have an International Drivers License when you travel abroad. Specially if your license is not in the langauge of the country you want to travel.